# Convert JSON file to a excel file in R or matlab

Tags: json

I have a rather huge JSON file which I want to convert to a excel file so that I can use it for feature selection.

Any suggestions on steps to import  the JSON file and convert it to an excel file with column names?
THnaks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to parse these json in key value pair using some programming language and store these key and value pair in excel file using coding and it will be easy way in my case.